# z-index not appearing correctly in chrome with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have pasted js fiddle link below and this issue is that the #aboutmetoggle div is appearing behind the #pic div and the #line div is showing in front on #pic. I need #pic and #line to show behind #aboutmetoggle.

It appears fine IE firefox, and safari but not in chrome. I've checked for any extra or open tags and can't see anything and the div are absolutely positioned and appear in the right order. Can anyone help as this is leaving me a bit stumped.....

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gkDcw/)

On the js fiddle the #line div is appearing too far over completely. Clearly this code is messed up... :-(

This site is asking me to place code within the question so below is the html for the page, but its in the fiddle anyway :-)

```
<div id="container"><div id="banner"><h1><img src="images/banner.png" width="432" height="64" alt="front end web designer" /></h1>
</div>
```

```
  <div id="pic"><img src="images/me.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="me" /></div>**


<a href="#" name="hiremetoggle" title="Hire me" id="hiremetoggle">
    <img src="images/hire.png"  alt="Hire me " border="0"/></a></div>

    <a href="#" name="prevtoggle" title="Previous work" id="prevtoggle"><img src="images/work.png" alt="Previous work" border="0"/>
    </a></div>


<div id="line"></div>




<div id="prevcontent">

<div class="img-wrap"><img src="images/example2.png" alt="Dr Martens fan site" /> <div class="img-info"><a href="http://www.webdesignerlhm.co.uk/drmartensfansite" target="_blank"><h2><br />Dr Martens Fansite</h2> </a></div></div>
<div id="block"> </div>

<div class="img-wrap2"><img src="images/example1.png" width="165" height="165" alt="Rainbow Feet holistic therapy college project e-commerce site" /> 
  <div class="img-info"><a href="http://www.webdesignerlhm.co.uk/rainbowfeet/holistic.html" target="_blank"><h2><br />Rainbow Feet</h2> a college project website</h2> </a></div></div>





<div id="blockrow"></div>



<div class="img-wrap4"><img src="images/example3.png"  width="230" height="165
" alt="Band style website" border="0"/><div class="img-info4"><a href="http://www.webdesignerlhm.co.uk/bandsite/" target="_blank"><h2><br />Band template website</h2></a></div></div>
<div class="img-wrap3"><img src="images/Misfestwebsite.jpg" width="258" height="165" /><div class="img-info3"><a href="http://www.misfest.co.uk" target="_blank"><h2><br/><br/>Misfest festival website</h2></a></div></div> 
<div id="rowblock" ></div><div id="rowblock"></div><div id="rowblock"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: any chance you can post an image of how this is expected to look? boxes and lines would be fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you have a `position:absolute` on the `#aboutmetoggle` and he is searching for his closest parent with a non absolute position declared to be placed. This parent is `#container` who has `position:fixed` and because it's under the divs me and pic then the `#aboutmetoggle` is under all.

Three possible solutions:

1. Remove `the position:fixed` from the container.
2. Give a `z-index` greather than 2 for the container.
3. Place the `#aboutmetoggle` in other site of your html structure where his parent can be the body.

All depends on what you can do and what you want to do because your Fiddle doesn't help.

Comment: Hi, I changed the containers position to absolute and reduced the z-index number of #aboutmetoggle and it appears how it should. Many many thanks for that :-) Just to clarify then #aboutmetoggle is the child of #me and #pic then even with a higher z:index it will not appear above them above if the position is different? or is it because #aboutmetoggle is absolute and they are not?? Thanks